# Calculate date difference and return number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, rtf, bi-publisher

I need help to calculate the date difference and return number of days.
I used this in rtf template but it didnt work and when i hard code the dates it works!and not sure what is wrong with the data field.
UDRDAILYACTDATEDO this is variable,
UDRFCDDATEDO this is fixed date when the contract starts, and I need to calculate the cumulative days from first chargeable date FCD.

and when i try to calculate the days inside the data set in BI usining numtodsinterval it return the seconds along with the number and couldnt find a way to truncate it.

Comment: This is what i used inside rtf template <?xdofx:TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(to_date(UDRDAILYACTDATEDO,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'J')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(to_date(UDRFCDDATEDO,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'J'))?>

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server and/or SQL?